# repo sync command, is it possible to sync only the repositories that I have permission to? I want to ignore the permission denied error

Tags: git-repo

When executing the repo sync command, is it possible to sync only the repositories that I have permission to? I want to ignore the permission denied error.

I created a google repo manifest file that manages many git repositories.
A lot of people use this. Some of them dont have access to the repository. This is intended.

I want him to clone only repositories he has permission to locally via the repo sync command.
However, this causes an error and even the authorized repository is not cloned. Any workaround?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBwAe.png)

only clone repository if he have permission..

Comment: Please add the error message as text rather than an image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [the docs](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/repo#sync), you can use the `-f` option to sync other projects even if some projects fail.

> Here are key options. See repo help sync for more:

> - `-f`: Proceed with syncing other projects even if a project fails to sync.